# how to connect sqlite and node js into react-electon

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, electron

i a trying to create a crossplatform desktop app using electron i have createed front-end with [react and electon](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/)  i know electon is build on top of nodejs i dont know where i can write the codes  creating api for fetching and inserting data from database

i want to bundle react-nodejs and mongodb as a single app and give to the client so they can easily install the app in their pc and start using the app

i have read the mongodb cannot be bundle like the way i reqired and sqlite can be used if that is the only case help me install sqlite

it woud be great if i can add express js insted of nodejs

this is my current folder structure

[image]

Comment: You read right, mongodb is not embeddable db. Express would likely be an overkill for an electron app. How do you intend to use it anyway? And regarding  "help me install sqlite" could you be more specific what help you expect?  The database is just a local file, and the client is an npm package.

Comment: What I am trying is. i trying to make a client desktop application that works offline  so for storing data I want a data base  , as  I told in the question I have used react-electon   so I was able to start writing the code for react js  just after installation from app.js  similary where can I wriite the code for node js APIs  APIs that's will communicate with the  db that is a local file as u said  i will be shiping this desktop application to my client as a single exe file that he can just install and use

Comment: If I make a file called index.js and start writing  APIs to fetch data from sqllite will it work ?? ( Since react js already has a index.js it will be treated as the part of react js and not as part of node js ) so what should I do to write code of node js

Comment: @AlexBlex the help I need for installing sqllite is the code that I need to write for connecting between the local db file and index.js( of node js)

Comment: It seems you misunderstand architecture of electron app. Although it does use html for presentation layer and can benefit from react components, it's not a web application with REST or GraphQL backend. It's still a desktop app - a nodejs process which spawns a chromium window. I'd suggest to go through some basic tutorials, pay attention how https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer works, may be vivisect some hello-world applications written by others. Then adding a new package to work with sqlite will be trivial.

Comment: @AlexBlex so ur telling with react-electron  i cannot store data to sqlite  and fectch data

Comment: hmm, where did I said that? The last sentence in my previous comment claims exactly opposite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247550/discussion-between-jisa-ks-and-alex-blex).

Comment: can u pls walk me throgh the steps that i should do inoder to store data in sqlite from react

Comment: I'm afraid Stackoverflow format is not quite suitable for walk-through or pair-programming exercises. Please read the docs I referred to to understand how frontend talks to the backend in electron. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc has some bite-size code snippets, and https://github.com/tarikguney/electron-with-sqlite3 has all the code specific to sqlite.

Comment: maybe this could help you https://github.com/dodandeniya/todolist-app

Comment: @LeslieAlldridge its simply says u can use sqlite it does not tell how u can use it